# AWS System Managers + CodeDeploy + Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, amazon-lightsail, amazon-kms, aws-ssm

I want to use AWS System Managers Store Parameters with my CodeDeploy pipeline, dropping my last commit on Lightsail.

**✅ 1. I created a SSM Parameters : `MySecureString`.**

The parameters is set on `SecureString` with KMS encryption set on `Actual account` with `alias/aws/ssm` as ID.

My `SecureString` is set as : `postgres://user:password@endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/myDatabase`

**✅ 2. I created an IAM Policies used by CodeDeploy instance**

Went to IAM and created a JSON policies attached to `MySpecificCodeDeployUser` :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "ssm:GetParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:*:<accountID>:key/alias/aws/ssm",
                "arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:<accountID>:parameter/MySecureString"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**✅ 3. Testing that `MySpecificFCodeDeployUser` access SSM `MySecureString` :**

Typped `aws configure` to logged as `MySpecificFCodeDeployUser` and try to run this command on my local computer :

```
aws --region=us-east-1 ssm get-parameter --name MySecureString --with-decryption --query Parameter.Value
RETURN ==> "postgres://user:password@endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/myDatabase"
```

Note that removing the IAM policies give me an Unauthorized request, so the IAM policy is correct.

**4. Adding `MySecureString` to script executed by CodeDeploy :**

Editing my `AfterInstall` script of my `appspec.yml` to add :

```
aws --region=us-east-1 ssm get-parameter --name MySecureString --with-decryption --query Parameter.Value >> .env
```

Gave me an a `FAILED Build` with `stderr` :

```
[stderr] An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetParameter operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<id>:assumed-role/AmazonLightsailInstanceRole/<id> is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:<id>:parameter/MySecureString
```

I saw that Lightsail instance inherit from service-linked roles `AWSServiceRoleForLightsail` from https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-service-linked-roles.

Is there a way to add a new policy to my lightsail instance regarding the fact that it didn't seems to be CodeDeploy user needing it ?

Comment: Any stderr logs?

Comment: Where can I retrieve stderr from CodeDeploy ? When I went to my deployment, everything is marked as success (green flag).

Comment: Try `&>` and see what you get

Comment: `&>` in my `AfterInstall` script ?

Comment: yep, replace `>>` with `&>`

Comment: Same result after deploying. Success but my `.env` is empty.

Comment: That's weird. This means that no stderr is logged.

Comment: Can you run it as `aws --region=us-east-1 ssm get-parameter --name MySecureString --with-decryption --query Parameter.Value &> .env` (no echo, just the aws command).

Comment: Nice ! I got `Failed - ScriptFailed`, but the error isn't clear : `Script at specified location: scripts/after_install.sh run as user bitnami failed with exit code 255` is it possible that it cames from my `appspec.yml` which got `runas: bitnami` ?

Comment: I managed to get an explicit log, as I understand, the IAM role I deployed should not be for `CodeDeploy` but for the `LightSail` instance. Is it possible to do that ? `[stderr]An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetParameter operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<id>:assumed-role/AmazonLightsailInstanceRole/<id> is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:<id>:parameter/MySecureString`

Comment: After some research, I found that LightSail inherit from IAM linked-roles that doesn't seems editable to add a specific permission : https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-service-linked-roles any clue on that ? Thanks.

Comment: If you want for a specific person to get notified about your comment, you need @Marcin tag them. Otherwise, no one will know you responded back to them.

Comment: The error says that you are using `AmazonLightsailInstanceRole` role. In the question you are listing different role, called `MySpecificCodeDeployUser`? You have to find `AmazonLightsailInstanceRole` and add ssm and kms permissions to that role.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. I didn't create `AmazonLightsailInstanceRole` which seems inherited from AWS Lightsail linked-role. From my research right now, it doesn't seems possible to add a specific IAM policy to `AmazonLightsailInstanceRole`. Is it possible to execute `CodeDeploy` scripts with another role or instance than `AmazonLightsailInstanceRole` which seems to be my Lightsail Instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to add a new policy to my lightsail instance regarding the fact that it didn't seems to be CodeDeploy user needing it ?

Sadly, you **can't do this**. To enable your applications on the lightsail instance to interact with AWS services, you have to do it yourself, by setting up `.aws` credentials and having your app using that (done automatically if you use AWS SDK).

Lightsail instances **don't support** user-based instance roles. For that you need regular EC2 instance as explained in:

- [Identity and Access Management for Amazon Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/security_iam)

Comment: As I undestand, it is possible to give the good right to the Lightsail instance, using a `.aws` or AWS SDK in my app, right @Marcin ?

Comment: @GuillaumeRZ Yes. You have to do it as you would on your local workstation.

Comment: @GuillaumeRZ How did it go? Any progress?

Comment: It works. Thanks. What I did : `aws configure` on my Lightsail instance, then create an Access Key on IAM for `MySpecificCodeDeployUser` and then paste the `secret key` and `key ID`.

Comment: @GuillaumeRZ Good it worked, but dissapointing the the bounty lapsed for the question :-(

Comment: Sorry, took me some time to understand that it is possible only by using `aws configure` on the Lightsail instance... :(

Comment: Double check that you are in the SAME user than the CodeDeploy one (root, ec2-user, ...).